# Django, global template variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a base template file (base.html) and every other template extends to it and generates content using its blocks. Certain variables, such as nav_obj, are used in the base template file.

View:

```
nav_obj = NavigationObject.objects.all()
```

Base template:

```
{% for object in nav_obj %}
<a href="{{ object.link }}">{{ object.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

At the moment, I need to pass nav_obj in every view. Is there any way to have this sent automatically?

Comment: did you solved out ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Write your own [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: Thanks! Good details here : http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/

Comment: I've a question regarding global variables in Django views. Can please provide your views ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490843/django-app-level-variables

Comment: Can you please provide the code to do this?

Answer (score 9):

[Inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) might be a good-looking alternative to a context processor.

Answer (score 7):

As the accepted answers already says, use context processors. Here's how to make them work with the current Django version:

First, create a function which accepts a request and returns a dictionary with your global template variables:

```
def load_nav_obj(request):
    nav_obj = NavigationObject.objects.all()
    return {'nav_obj': nav_obj}
```

A good place for this function would be in a file `context_processors.py` in your main app.

Now, tell your app to use this context processor for all rendered templates. In your  `settings.py`, add `myapp.context_processors.load_nav_obj` in the `TEMPLATE` settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your context processors here
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                ...
                'myapp.context_processors.load_nav_obj',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

That's it! You can now use the variable `{{nav_obj}}` in all templates!

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative, redirect here: [Defining "global variable" in Django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030249/defining-global-variable-in-django-templates/7252078#7252078)

Snippet example usage:

```
{% setglobal foo 0 %}
value={% getglobal foo %}
{% incrementglobal foo 0 %}
value={% setglobal foo %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at Django-navbar for it's documentation and tests..

Answer (score 0):

One easy workaround, I found is to create a simple Django template tag that will add the variables to the request object.

Example template tag:

```
# myapp/templatetags/custom_tags.py

from django import template
from.your_app.models import NavigationObject

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def nav_list(context):
    request = context['request']
    navigation_list = NavigationObject.objects.all()
    request.navigation_list = navigation_list
return ''
```

Then in your template:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
<!-- Add the custom template tag to set the global variable -->
{% nav_list %}
<!-- You can access the global variable as request.navigation_list -->
<h5>{{ request.navigation_list }}</h5>
```

This method will only work for templates that are loaded after the template tag is loaded, however, it has the added benefit of not needing to use a Context processor that will include the variable in every single template, which is very rarely needed.