# How can I send data to a base template in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Let's say I have a django site, and a base template for all pages with a footer that I want to display a list of the top 5 products on my site. How would I go about sending that list to the base template to render? Does every view need to send that data to the render_to_response? Should I use a template_tag? How would you do it?

Comment: Although I already answered, the question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030249/defining-global-variable-in-django-templates , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223429/django-global-template-variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use a [custom context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). With this you can set a variable e.g. `top_products` that will be available in all your templates.

E.g.

```
# in project/app/context_processors.py
from app.models import Product

def top_products(request):
    return {'top_products': Products.objects.all()} # of course some filter here
```

In your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # maybe other here
    'app.context_processors.top_products',
)
```

And in your template:

```
{% for product in top_products %}
    ...
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. It sounds just like what I was looking for.

Comment: Just a remainder. Process of adding context processor is changed in later version of Django. OP's quest can be satisfied according to this question's accepted answer also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902707/how-can-i-pass-data-to-django-layouts-like-base-html-without-having-to-provi