# How can i pass data to django layouts (like 'base.html') without having to provide it through every view?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to pass the data to layout `'base.html'`. I am currently doing it by storing the data in `request.session` and accessing it in `'base.html'` through request object.

Is there any way to pass the data to `'base.html'` without having to pass the data from every views?

Comment: Yes, context processors or middleware, both are heavily documented

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use a context processor, which is made exactly for that purpose. Create a file `context_processors.py` in one of your app directories, then in the file define a function that return a dictionary of variables to insert in every template context, something like this:

```
def add_variable_to_context(request):
    return {
        'testme': 'Hello world!'
    }
```

Enable your context processor in the settings (django>=1.8):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [root('templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'yourapp.context_processors.add_variable_to_context',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then in every template you can write

`{{ testme }}`

And it will render as

`Hello world!`

More info in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)

Comment: Great. This suffice my purpose. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can also use custom filters.

Comment: What to do if the data to be injected is dynamic in nature

Comment: @HassanBaig you can customize the `add_variable_to_context` function to your needs. E.g. you can import Django models, do some queries and inject some dynamic content in every template. In the example I used a string literal just to keep the code simple to understand.

Answer (score 4):

If you need this data in (almost) every template, then it makes sense to use a context processor. From the django docs:

> The context_processors option is a list of callables – called context processors – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context.

[Django docs on Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)