# Reorder nav bar from django admin

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, navigation-drawer

So I am currently working on a project and the client has asked for this requirement.

Basically, I have to provide some sort of mechanism in the admin panel so that the admin can order the navbar items.
[Current nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFc8A.png)
Like in the image above, admin should be able to set the order to eg. SIGN-IN SIGN-UP ABOUT HOME

I'm new to Django but have decent programming skill. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Home, About, Signup, SignIn is the best practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make the navbar display data-driven.

1. Create a model for the navbar display.

```
from django.db import models

class Navbar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    display_order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

2. Register the model so the user can modify in the admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Navbar

admin.site.register(Navbar)
```

3. Create objects for the model class for each of the desired navbar links.
4. Use content_processors to pass the navbar object to the template that contains the navbar (generally base.html). This link explains in detail how to use content processors.

[How can i pass data to django layouts (like 'base.html') without having to provide it through every view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902707/how-can-i-pass-data-to-django-layouts-like-base-html-without-having-to-provi/34903331)

Your function in content_processors.py should be similar to this.

```
from .models import Navbar
def add_navbar_data_to_base(request):
    return {
        'navbar': Navbar.objects.all().order_by('display_order')
    }
```

5. Now you can add the links to base.html template using a for loop and they will display in the order specified by the display_order which can be modified in the admin.

```
#base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    {% block nav %}
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand navbar-light">

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
           {% for link in navbar %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">{{ link }}</a>
            </li>
           {% endfor %}

        </ul>
    </nav>

    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

This code has not been tested but the general idea should work.