# Django admin add context to index.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin, django-context

I'm trying to override Django admin index.html to show table contain latest 5 records from a model

I managed to override the template with the following in my app:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.index_template = 'admin/dashboard.html'
admin.autodiscover()
```

But i have no idea how to add the latest records from model as a context to the index.html

Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CustomAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        # Add your context here
        return super(CustomAdminSite, self).index(request, extra_context)

admin_site = CustomAdminSite()
```

Don't forget to replace default `admin` with `admin_site`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but could you explain where to replace the default admin with admin_site? 
I'm trying to accomplish that my index page in admin gets additional data, and I think I understand the first part. But I'm a bit confused about the second part. 
I already have a custom, limited, admin site, by selecting limited fields and using "path('admin/', user_admin_site.urls), but I would like to pass additional context in the index version. What would I need to add a side from the above class?

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me to add extra context was using context processor. Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903331/13436391

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors)