# Whats the best way to duplicate data in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my template, more or less. The h1 heading is always the same as the title tag. The above snippet of code is not valid because there can't be two blocks with the same name. How do I handle this without repeating myself?

---

edit to clarify: I have a ton of child templates which are inherited from this one template, and so making a new {{title}} variable for each template is not a very good solution. Previously I had it set up like this:

base.html:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

then in base_view.html (extending base.html):

```
<h1>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</h1>
```

then in base_object.html (extending base_view.html):

```
{% block title %}my title goes here{% endblock %}
```

and it just worked somehow. I refactored my templates so theres just base.html, and base_object.html How can I get this functionality back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like your layout is solid. You have a `base.html` template that defines the basic structure and outer layout for each page in your app. You also have `base_object.html` that extends this template.

You'd like each page to have a unique title and a matching h1 (I think). This best way to do this is to define two separate blocks in your base.html template.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}Default Title{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>{% block h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your child templates, you need to override both of these if you'd like them to be identical. I know you feel this is counter-intuitive, but it is necessary due to the way template inheritance is handled in Django.

Source: [The Django template language](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#id1)

> Finally, note that you can't define multiple `{% block %}` tags with the same name in the same template. This limitation exists because a block tag works in "both" directions. That is, a block tag doesn't just provide a hole to fill -- it also defines the content that fills the hole in the parent. If there were two similarly-named `{% block %}` tags in a template, that template's parent wouldn't know which one of the blocks' content to use.

The children look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block h1 %}Title{% endblock %}
```

If this bothers you, you should set the title from the view for each object as a template variable.

```
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block h1 %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
```

Django strives to keep as much logic out of the template layer as possible. Often a title is determined dynamically from the database, so the view layer is the perfect place to retrieve and set this information. You can still leave the title blank if you'd like to defer to the default title (perhaps set in `base.html`, or you can grab the name of the site from the `django.contrib.sites` package)

Also `{{ block.super }}` may come in handy. This will allow you to combine the contents of the parent block with additional contents from the child. So you could define a title like "Stackoverflow.com" in the base, and set

```
{% block title %}{{ block.super }} - Ask a Question{% endblock %}
```

in the child to get a title like "Stackoverflow.com - Ask a Question"

Answer (score 25):

In base.html:

```
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>{% block h1 %}{% endblock %}</h1>
</body>
```

Then, make another "base" layer on top of that called content_base.html (or something):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block h1 %}{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% endblock %}
```

Now have all your other templates extend content_base.html.  Whatever you put in block "title" in all your templates will go into both "title" and "h1" blocks in base.html.

Comment: Ouch, but I suppose it'll work.

Comment: works! efficient and simple and somehow a hack, but works.

Answer (score 13):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% with "Entry Title" as title %}
    {% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
    {% block h1 %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

That could work if you're *really* worried about keeping `title` out of the views and not repeating yourself.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Pass a variable to your template, maybe called title.  Then replace your title block with {{ title }}.  To pass this into your template in your view make sure you have:

```
def myview(request):
    t = loader.get_template("mypage.html")
    title = "My Title"
    c = Context({"title" : title })
    HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Then in your template you will have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}}</h1>
</body>
```

See also: [How to repeat a "block" in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511067/how-to-repeat-a-block-in-a-django-template)

Comment: This is not how Django should be used.

Comment: @Frank Crook: Care to explain?

Comment: @csunwold: I don't really have time, or I'd just have answered the question. To be brief, the question comes from someone who has a fundamental misunderstanding of how blocks and inheritance work in Django's templating system. Your answer doesn't clarify this for them, instead it jumps over the subject of blocks and inheritance completely and shows an example where they are not used at all.

Comment: +1: Use this all the time.  Works great.

Comment: What Frank mentioned, in other words: static content should never be defined in views. They pertain to the template-land, and there should be defined.