# CopyBlock tag for Django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

How can I write a tag "copyblock" for Django templates?

For such a function:

```
<title> {% block title %} some title... {% endblock %} </title>
<h1>{% copyblock title %}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solutions mentioned in this question:

- [How to repeat a "block" in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511067/how-to-repeat-a-block-in-a-django-template)

Answer (score 1):

Django's template parser doesn't expose blocks by name. Instead, they are organized into a tree structure in the Django `Template`'s `nodelist`, with rendering `push`ing and `pop`ping on the stack of template nodes. You'll have a nearly impossible time accessing them in the way your example indicates.

The SO link that ars references provides suggestions on the best solutions. Of those solutions, defining a variable in the context (ie: `{{ title }}` in the spirit of your example) that can be reused is probably the most straightforward and maintainable approach. If the piece you want to duplicate goes beyond a simple variable, a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) is probably the most appealing option.

Comment: +1: Focus on the `{{ title }}` and providing extra context.  Custom template tags are rarely worth the effort.