# Generate same text with and without HTML tags?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django 1.9. I would like to generate a couple of sentences in a template to use both in the front-end of the app, and in the meta description tag.

In the template, I would like it to include links:

```
<p><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url}}">{{ object.name }}</a> blah blah...</p>
```

But in the meta description, I obviously don't want to include those links - I just need it to be plain text (but the same content):

```
{% block page_description %}{{ object.name }}</a> blah blah{% endblock page_description %}
```

Ideally I would use a template tag to include the same sentence in both places in the template, but how can I generate one version without links and one with, in a DRY way?

Comment: Could you check for this in your view? If you have an HttpRequest then you know it's on a website, then you can return html, otherwise return non HTML text? (Or does the front end still use HttpRequest?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one way to do it would be to:

1. Generate two times the HTML text by writing it once in a template
2. Process one of the two HTML texts above to remove the tags

For the first part, I suggest you have a look at [How to repeat a "block" in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511067/how-to-repeat-a-block-in-a-django-template).

Then, you can create two template tags `{% striphtml %}` and `{% endstriphtml %}` to convert everything that is in between to plain text:

```
import lxml.html

def do_striphtml(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endstriphtml',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return StripHtmlNode(nodelist)

class StripHtmlNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
    def render(self, context):
        html = self.nodelist.render(context)
        doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
        return doc.text_content()
```

This is inspired from "[Parsing until another block tag, and saving contents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag-and-saving-contents)" of the Django doc, and uses `lxml.html` to remove the HTML tags.

Putting everything together, the templates should look like:

```
# base.html
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <meta name="description" content="{% striphtml %}{% block description %}Meta description{% endblock %}{% endstriphtml %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and then:

```
# the_page.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% block description %}
        <p>Content that will appear in the body (with tags) and in the meta description (without tags).</p>
    {% endblock %}
    Content not to be included in the meta tag.
{% endblock %}
```

That's all untested, so let us known if it works!