# Wrapping content with the same tags multiple times in Django templates

Tags: html, django

Given a base.html file containing the following:

```
<div class="foo some-content">
    ...content...
</div>
<div class="bar some-content">
    ...different content...
</div>
```

I would like to wrap each of the `.some-content` divs to achieve a nested structure when using base.html in certain places:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="foo some-content">
      ...content...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="bar some-content">
      ...different content...
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried extending base.html to wrap the divs with a `.row` div:

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block wrapper %}
 <div class "row">
  {{ block.super }}
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But that didn't work as I got a `TemplateSyntaxError` for using `block wrapper` twice in base.html:

```
  # Throws TemplateSyntaxError
  {% block wrapper %}
    <div class="foo some-content">
      ...content...
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
  {% block wrapper %}
    <div class="bar some-content">
      ...different content...
    </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

I realize that I could break up the `.some-content` divs in to their own files, and reuse those in other places, but I would prefer another route. I also looked at [Django template macros](https://pypi.org/project/django-templates-macros/) as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462015/3071419), but I think middleware will be overkill in this situation.

Is there any way I can extend or reuse my current base.html file so that the `.some-content` divs are sometimes wrapped in a `.row` div?

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like:

```
{% with foo as var %}
{% include 'mycontainer.html' %}
{$ endwith %}
{% with bar as var %}
{% include 'mycontainer.html' %}
{$ endwith %}
```

Then mycontainer.html would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="{{ var }} some-content">
  ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe my original question did not make it clear that the `some-content` divs contain different content, so this doesn't solve it. I've tweaked the examples so that this is more clear.